# "String object not callable" python object programming question

Tags: python, object

I wrote such code and I do not understand why I cannot call full_name() function the same way I can call show_info() function?
How to fix this error (string object not callable)?

```
class Cake:

   bakery_offer = []

   def __init__(self, name, kind, taste, additives, filling):

       self.name = name
       self.kind = kind
       self.taste = taste
       self.additives = additives.copy()
       self.filling = filling
       self.bakery_offer.append(self)

   def show_info(self):
       print("{}".format(self.name.upper()))
       print("Kind:        {}".format(self.kind))
       print("Taste:       {}".format(self.taste))
       if len(self.additives) > 0:
           print("Additives:")
           for a in self.additives:
               print("\t\t{}".format(a))
       if len(self.filling) > 0:
           print("Filling:     {}".format(self.filling))
       print('-' * 20)

   @property
   def full_name(self):
       return "--== {} - {} ==--".format(self.name.upper(), self.kind)

cake01 = Cake('Vanilla Cake', 'cake', 'vanilla', ['chocolate', 'nuts'], 'cream')
cake01.show_info()
cake01.full_name()
```

Comment: Why exactly did you put that `@property` there?

Comment: Please include the full traceback message

Comment: `cake01.full_name()` tells python to lookup "full_name" on the `cake01` object and then call that found object. But since "full_name" is a property returning a string, the found object is not callable. `cake01.full_name` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `full_name` as a `@property` and not a regular method, so now `cake01.full_name` will already call it and give you the string result which your function returned, as opposed to `cake01.full_name()` as it would normally be without `@property`. The extra `()` therefore result to call a string and not a function.

It's different from `cake01.show_info()` because there you didn't use `@property`.

The right way to use your property would be:

```py
print(cake01.full_name)
```

See also: https://realpython.com/python-property/